# В чем разница между track, set-upstream-to и set-upstream?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Не могу разобраться в теме "отслеживания веток"

Есть 3 команды которые вроде как выставляют для ветки отслеживание на удаленную ветку:

```
git branch --track 
git branch --set-upstream-to 
git branch --set-upstream
```

По мне, так они делают одно и тоже. Я не понимаю, зачем тогда их аж 3 штуки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

флаг `--track` можно использовать только при создании новых бранчей

Флаги `--set-upstream` и `--set-upstream-to` меняют upstream для уже существующего бранча (если не указан `--force`). Можно считать `--track` шорткатом для `--set-upstream --force`

Новый `--set-upstream-to` отличается от старого `--set-upstream` порядком аргументов, что позволяет менять upstream для текущего бранча без явного указания его имени:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```